# How do I get a specific <TD> value?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm facing a troubles around jQuery and HTML elements.
Let's to the "Artists":

```
<table id="tableBenef" width="375px">
     <tr style="border-bottom: solid 1px silver;">
         <td style="width: 10%"> Action </td>
         <td style="width: 45%"> Nome   </td>
         <td style="width: 20%"> Data Nasc </td>
         <td style="width: 25%"> Grau Parent </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

This above is the Table Header and Inside of it I add dinamically new Rows. Each row contains  a Checkbox and three more TDs, also I have three text inputs which I send each of one to the referent TD, the checkbox is for Delete purposes.

The question is, How to Get those new values inserted dinamically with jQuery?!
I started with this code below:

```
 function getRowValues() {
            var table = $("#tableBenef");
            $(table).each(function () {
                alert($(this).text());
            })
        };
```

But I'm facing trouble with that, could someone help me on this?

In negative case, thanks anyway!
Sorry for any mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheap solution: don't get them back from the HTML at all. Instead, before inserting each row into the HTML, store that row's values in an array. Then, just read the array rather than having to go all the way back through the DOM.

As requested, here is some very basic code for how you'd go about doing this. (Obviously, this is just code to illustrate the general idea, since I don't know your actual setup.)

```
var insertedRowData = [];

function insertRow(rowValues) {
  // I'm assuming that rowValues is in the form {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"}.
  // That sort of generic object is probably a good format for storage,
  // but it doesn't matter what format you use, so long as it is a single object
  // that can be stored now and accessed later.

  insertedRowData[insertedRowData.length] = rowValues;

  /*
    ...
    Insert the row into the table, like you're already doing.
    ...
  */
}

function handleRowValues() {
  // Hey, look! All of the data is still stored in insertedRowData.
  // I can now handle it in whatever way I want. I think I'll log them
  // to Chrome or Firebug's console, but you can do whatever you want here.

  console.log(insertedRowData);
}
```

Comment: Hi Matchu, thanks for ask.
How get those values later? Could you make a bit of code with this?!

Comment: @FelipeKM: I added some very basic code for illustration's sake. Essentially, create an object of the form's data in whatever form you like (I'd use key-value pairs), then store each of those objects in an array for later.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying `.each()` on the table, not on the cells. You need to add method getting specific descendants (in this case, table cells). Do it like that ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RbJZc/)):

```
function getRowValues() {
    var table = $("#tableBenef");
    $(table).find('td').each(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    })
};
```

Note the additional `.find('td')` doing exactly what I described.

Was it helpful?

Comment: Yeah right, but I have to "jump" the first one because it is the Menu, right? I need to get the another one row, How would do I that?

Comment: @FelipeKM What is the menu? If you are using tables for the navigation, you are doing it wrong. If you want to go to the next row, you can do it in two ways - first of all, my current answer goes through _all cells_ (that means does not matter, in which row they are). You can just iterate through each row ('tr'), and then for each cell ('td') within this row. Also if you have column and row headers, enclose them in '<th>' instead of '<td>'. Just combine these solutions, post your own and we will help you.